# php start download from url

Tags: php, url, curl

I want to access to a website, like "http://www.ariva.de/US922646AS37/historische_kurse?boerse_id=1", changing the dates in the "CSV" section and then start the download. On the website, one has to push the button download. Is there a possibility to do it automatically by using php?

Comment: yes. Google for "PHP cURL"

Answer (score 1):

First download what you need through cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "URL HERE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Then process the data as needed. After that:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($File) . "\"");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($File));
header("Connection: close");
```

Comment: This is wrong, he needs to download a file FROM a third party website, not to offer a download from his own website.

Comment: +1 - I've edited the post lightly to allow me to remove the downvote, now the answer is correct